# C (Embedded) : Giving source file unique ID's

Tags: c, embedded, c-preprocessor

I'm working on a compact debug output/unit testing utility to be used on embedded systems.

I've created a system where I can output messages over a serial port to the PC in a compact manner. 
To save memory space/serial port bandwidth I've stripped message strings from the embedded system by giving them unique 16-bit ID's.

This was pretty straight forward because I put all messages in 1 list. A few macro's would put this into an enumeration:

projectdefs.h:

```
#define MESSAGE_TABLE(MSG) \
    MSG(HELLO, "Hello World!") \
    MSG(TEST, "Second message #ID 1") \
    MSG(TEST2, "Third message #ID 2")
```

messages.h:

```
#define MACRO_STR_CONCAT(a,b) a##b
#define MESSAGE_ENUM(codeName, str) MACRO_STR_CONCAT(MSG_, codeName)    

typedef enum messageNumbers_e {
    MESSAGE_TABLE(MESSAGE_ENUM),
    MESSAGE_COUNT
};

#define MESSAGE(codeName) messageSend(MACRO_STR_CONCAT(MSG_, codeName), __LINE__, file_number);
```

The only data transmitted over the serial port is the message ID, line number and file number (note; not string!).

The trouble I'm having is how can I assign an unique ID to every file using the **C** preprocessor/compiler. I don't want to store each filename string inside the embedded program. This uses (too much) memory or bandwidth on the serial port.

My idea is to define the constant file_number in each file with a macro. I would use this definition at the top of each source file:

```
#define ASSIGN_FILENUMBER() enum { file_number = __COUNTER__ };
```

However as each file is compiled separately this means the `__COUNTER__` statement always starts at 0 when called and doesn't know the presence of other files or it's own ID.

Another consideration was to edit the MakeFile (script) and add file ID numbers there. However, this would tie the project build/functionality tightly to my IDE configuration, which is not desirable.
Moreover, I am uncertain about the possibility with my current IDE's (XC16/XC32 compiler on Mplab X IDE or IAR Embedded Workbench).

I wonder if there is any other creative ways to have a standard **C** preprocessor take over task?

Comment: Does your compiler support precompiled headers? Precompiled header may persist the `__COUNTER__` value, at least this is written in MSVC documentation.

Comment: Would it be fine if you generated a unique ID dynamically with an O(1) algorithm? Or am I not getting the question :o

Comment: I've tried to manually precompile a headerfile with the `ASSIGN_FILENUMBER` macro. My compiler is likely gcc-based, but doesn't boast it.
I can see the precompiled header file is picked up (-H output), however, proccesor-specific definitions fail to compile: `invalid attribute space, __sfr__, __unsafe__, etc. ignored`. 
As embedded software written in C are complete static programs it doesn't make sense to dynamically allocate/calculate ID's inside the device. Moreover, it would be harder to track for the host.

Comment: Since the C preprocessor does not know how many files are going to be compiled to make your program, I think the C preprocessor would have a   hard time helping.

Comment: While not the C preprocessor, you could probably have the makefile run a shell/python/perl script which would regenerate the list and constants before building the code.  But a more common option would be to just dump the code address (and perhaps version or build epoch time), and translate it back to file/source on the development machine with a tool that references the map file or similar toolchain debug output (which you would need to preserve, but not actually load onto the target system).

Comment: I've implemented the prebuild script option. Works pretty well in MPLAB X, need to see how it goes on other IDE's.
Precompiled file headers ended up with a big fail at XC16. I got rid of the invalid attribute warnings (including the faulty xc.h header in the precompiled header), but hit a brick wall with 'internal compiler error; segmentation fault'. :(
So indeed, C preprocessor seems to be ruled out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure that storing source code file names in the program is such a big deal for the memory. If you can have them, then one thing you could do is declare a variable like `const char *fname = __FILE__;` and then calculate some kind of checksum, hash or CRC and transmit this value instead of the file name. On the receiving side you can match the hash value to one of the the file names. You'll need to make sure that file name hashes don't collide, though.

Another approach would be to use your makefiles or perl or something to maintain a file counter and feed it as a macro into gcc, e.g. `gcc [someparams1] -DFILENUMBER=%FILECOUNTER% somefile.c [someparams2]`, where `%FILECOUNTER%` is whatever expression that'll expand into the file counter variable's value as text. You might need to introduce a fixed order of source file compilation here.

You could combine the two methods and feed gcc with the hash instead of the counter, e.g. `-DFILENAMEHASH=%HASH%`, where `%HASH%` would expand to a numeric constant that your compiling scripts would generate based on the file name.

Comment: It wouldn't be a big deal to store the strings on a desktop, but this question asks about an embedded application where it is often desirable/necessary to keep things very tight.

Comment: I've done what you and Chris suggested. I have added a pre-build program (little C# console program, but can be anything..) that reads the makefile, finds all build commands and adds a -DFILENUMBER parameter. I parse the makefile in my debug output program too so I can know what file number is which file.

Unfortunate there is no (solid) C solution for this, but this works and wasn't too troublesome.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered creating a 16-bit hash number based on whatever you get from **FILE**?  It may not be perfect (read collisions), but if might be good enough for your needs.  If  acceptable, you would need an external lookup table so you could map your hash number ID to the file in question.

Hope this idea helps.

Comment: This sounds like a runtime solution, which would not be compatible with the goal of keeping the strings out of the compiled code.

Comment: This would be an option if it could be done at compilation time through a macro of some sort. But I don't think that kind of arithmetic is possible with macro's?
What I want is a static file ID generated at build/compilation time.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to compute the HASH of the filename during the compilation. You can use the following macro (see http://lolengine.net/blog/2011/12/20/cpp-constant-string-hash):

```
// Compile time hash computation. Size of input string must be <256 bytes.
#define   H1(s, i, x)    (x * 65599u + (uint8_t)s[(i) < strlen(s) ? strlen(s) - 1 - (i) : strlen(s)])
#define   H4(s, i, x)  H1(s, i,  H1(s, i +  1,  H1(s, i +   2,  H1(s, i +   3, x))))
#define  H16(s, i, x)  H4(s, i,  H4(s, i +  4,  H4(s, i +   8,  H4(s, i +  12, x))))
#define  H64(s, i, x) H16(s, i, H16(s, i + 16, H16(s, i +  32, H16(s, i +  48, x))))
#define H256(s, i, x) H64(s, i, H64(s, i + 64, H64(s, i + 128, H64(s, i + 192, x))))
#define HASH(s) ((uint32_t)(H256(s, 0, 0) ^ (H256(s, 0, 0) >> 16)))
```

Then, thanks to `__COUNTER__` and `__FILE_NAME__`, you can easily write a macro that replace a trace by a unique number:

```
#define __LOG(val, msg, ...) \
    do {                                                    \
        if (USE_BINARY_TRACES)                              \
            print_as_bin(val, ##__VA_ARGS__);               \
        else                                                \
            print_as_ascii(msg, ##__VA_ARGS__);             \
    } while(0)

#define LOG(msg, ...) __LOG(HASH(__FILE_NAME__) + __COUNTER__, msg, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

However, you can go further. You can store the string versions of the traces and their associated ID in a specific section of your binary:

```
struct message {
    uint32_t id;
    const char content[];
};

#define __LOG(val, msg, ...) \
    do {                                                        \
        static const __attribute__((used, section(".rodata_traces"))) struct message __trace = { val, msg }; \
        fake_printf(msg, ##__VA_ARGS__);                        \
        if (USE_BINARY_TRACES)                                  \
            send_to_uart_bin(val, ##__VA_ARGS__);               \
        else                                                    \
            send_to_uart_ascii(msg, ##__VA_ARGS__);             \
    } while(0)

#define LOG(msg, ...) __LOG(HASH(__FILE_NAME__) + __COUNTER__, msg, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

So, the string associated to the numbers are stored in the section `.rodata_traces` of the binary:

```
$ objdump -j .rodata_traces -s binary_logs

binary_logs:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of section .rodata_traces:
  2008 d6caf741 576f726c 64000000 d5caf741  ...AWorld......A
  2018 48656c6c 6f00                        Hello.
```

You can now write a script that look up this table and translate your traces. Obviously, this table is not necessary for the runtime, you can strip it with `objcopy` (as you would do for debug symbols).